# GPS routing (Shortest path) in iPhone using Mapkit and Google map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, routes, mapkit, shortest-path

I am developing on Xcode 4.3.3, iOS 5 and using Mapkit library.
The app should show current location on Google map, get the destination address and finally draw the shortest path between those two points.

I used this tutorial for implementing the app and I have current location now:
http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/

I looked for routing but I haven't found any resource.
Please guide me how I can draw the shortest path between the current location and the destination.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this will only work for ios 6.

```
 Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {

            CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
            CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:getLatitude
                                                                longitude:getLongitude];

            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
                           completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                               MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];

                               MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

                               MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

                               NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

                               NSDictionary *options = @{
                           MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                           MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
                           MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
                               };

                               [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];

                           }         ];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you google for map kit and route?

You'd find this: http://inlight.com.au/posts/mapkit which explains how to use Google Maps and decode the response to extract points to get a route.

There's also a commercial kit: http://mtdirectionsk.it/

Answer (score 0):

iOS MapKit does not provide routing information for Apps as a service.   Instead, your choices now are either to get routing information from a third-party mechanism, or to build the routes yourself (which, if you don't have the underlying street data is basically impossible).

You might look at [CloudMade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-sdk) as an alternative map system if you need to provide routing information in your own App, or consider just calling Maps to route to a location if you want to take advantage of Apple's Map for navigation.

If you want to call out to the Map App for navigation, you basically need to open a URL with the source and destination location.   Here's an example:

```
    CLLocationManager *manager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [manager location].coordinate;
    NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", 
                      currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude];
    // used to be able to (3.2 iPad) "Current+Location", now we have to send: lat,long
    NSString *encodedAddress = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                 NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@", from, encodedAddress];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below ans work for all ios:
   NSString *deviceVersion   = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSLog(@"My Device version is :%@ ",deviceVersion);


    //*********  For ios 6 supporting devices  *********
    if ([deviceVersion isEqualToString:@"6.0"])
    {

        Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {

            CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
            CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:getLatitude
                                                                longitude:getLongitude];

            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
                           completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                               MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];

                               MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

                               MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

                               NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

                               NSDictionary *options = @{
                           MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                           MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
                           MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
                               };

                               [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];

                           }         ];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];

        }
    }
    //*********  For other ios supporting devices  *********
    else {

        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
        region.center.latitude = getLatitude;
        region.center.longitude = getLongitude;

        MKCoordinateRegion currentRegion = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
        currentRegion.center.latitude = currentLatitude;
        currentRegion.center.longitude = currentLongitude;

        region.span.longitudeDelta = 4.0f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 4.0f;
        currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 4.0f;
        currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 4.0f;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { currentRegion.center.latitude, currentRegion.center.longitude };
        CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude };

        NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

    }

}
```